# Javascript (Node.js) destructure json into existing variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

I'm wondering if it is possible to declare variables once in a method and then reuse them multiple times to capture destructured return values.

for eg:

```
  function verifyStatusAsSignedIn(url, cred){

     // code truncated

     return { 'error' : false, 'status': true }
  }
```

I can do declaration and destructure JSON at the same time.

```
 const { error , status } = verifyStatusAsSignedIn(url, cred);
```

But I have more methods that I call that will also return JSON with error and status just like the method 'verifyStatusAsSignedIn()' does.

I would ideally like to do this:

```
  let error, status;

  { error, status } = verifyStatusAsSignedIn(url, cred);

  //  handle or respond to error and status.

  { error, status } = nextStep(val1, val2);

  // handle or respond to error and status
```

But this gives me a lint warning 'Declaration or statement expected.

Is it possible to re-use existing variables to destructure a json object ?

Comment: it's not a good practice to reuse the same variable just because they are returned as same keys in the object, you can rename variables while destructing through `{ error: validationError, status: validationStatus } = verifyStatusAsSignedIn(url, cred);`

Comment: Thanks @AZ_. I'm deliberately returning the same keys and feel it is easier to read. long variable names become cumbersome at times. But what you've suggested is interesting, that I can rename them while destructuring. I'm going to try it out for other use cases as I think it will come in handy more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to surround it with parens like this to assign to existing variables:

```
let error, status;
({ error, status } = verifyStatusAsSignedIn(url, cred));
```

This is because without the parens, Javascript thinks the `{` is the start of a new block scope.  It's apparently one place where the destructuring assignment syntax ran into a conflict with existing syntax rules so it takes a work-around with the parens to use it this way.

You can see MDN describe this situation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration).

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for the quick response. That was easy, I'm going to try this out and come back to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I just tried it and got the following error 'SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'. Further research on this error suggested a variant that seems to work  - 
 ( { error, status} = verifyStatus(url, cred) );
  Notice the entire line is in parenthesis and not just the left hand side. Is this the correct way or your recommendation requires something special ?

Comment: @Curious101 - Yes, you're right.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've been able to test it successfully and have accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.